# JSON Renderkit - or how do I return JSON to a JSF client?

Tags: ajax, json, jsf, facelets

I am making an AJAX call using jQuery to a JSF 2.0 server.  The "page" I am calling looks something like this:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/jsonTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
    #{tabBean.jsonUrl}
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Where my jsonTemplate.xhtml looks something like this:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</html>
```

The result that is send to the client contains my JSON Object and the HTML tags, which I have to strip off on the client.

What I want returned is a pure JSON Object.

```
{ "url" : "/this/is/my/url.xhtml" }
```

On the client, I strip off the <HTML> and the </HTML> tags, use jQuery to parseJSON and return a JSON Object.  I tried to specify the template without the HTML tags and it complained.  Seems like this is the bare minimum response I can generate.

I would like to have a RenderKit that would enable me to return nothing but pure JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you tp use a RESTEasy library with a Jaxson provider. It's not hard to start with it.
After proper configuration you will need only to implement ajax request to a server.
Java code would be smth like:

```
@POST
@Path("/getPossiblePhases")
@Encoded
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Process> getPossiblePhases(@FormParam("prfID") Long prfID){
    return new List<Process>(); // some list here for example
}
```

and as response you will get only JSON. Ofc it supports xml, GET requests and have lots of other features. Supports Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't emit those HTML tags.

Replace

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</html>
```

By

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</ui:composition>
```

Much better is however indeed to use a webservice for this. JSF is a component based MVC framework, not a web service framework. Look at JAX-RS/JAX-WS.